# Apache Superset Dashboard Integration External Web App

Tags: angular, apache-superset

We are trying to integrate Apache Superset into an Angular App. We saw the option of Iframe with the dashboard url+ standalone=true. Unfortunately, the security layer blocks the iframe. We are redirected to login page.

Also, how can the Dashboard JSON data be retrieved from API (swagger api integrated) in order to be used to reproduce the HTML Dashboard?

The Apache Superset + Preset is not super helpful about Dashboard External Integration

Comment: relevant proposal on the Superset repo https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/17187

Comment: thanks @suddjian . that's exactly what I'm looking for